# Is it possible to simulate click on router-link element via another function in vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Is there a way to simulate click event on router-link element in vue. I put router-link element in my carousel because in there I have access to movie object which I need for to pass router-link params, but in there it is very hard to styled it properly, so I will use button outside of carousel and when clicked trigger a function to simulate click on router-link. Eventually I will hide router-link element and use only button from which I am passing click event to function doing the simulation. I am new to vue so please have mercy on me:)

Here is the code

```
 <v-carousel-item
        style="cursor:pointer"
        v-for="movie in popularMovies"
        :key="movie.title"
        :src="apiUrl + movie.poster_path"
      >
        <div class="carousel-title">
          <p>{{movie.title}}</p>
        </div>
        <router-link 
        :to="{ name: 'MovieDetails', params: { id: movie.id }}">
        VIEW MORE</router-link>
      </v-carousel-item>
    </v-carousel>
    <div style="text-align:center;">
      <v-btn @click="loadRouterLink">VIEW DETAILS</v-btn>
    </div>
```

and method

```
methods: {
    ...mapActions(["fetchPopularMovies"]),
    loadRouterLink () {
      //do something here to simulate click on router-link element
    }
  },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just like this

```
loadRouterLink (movieId) {
    this.$router.push({ name: 'MovieDetails', params: { id: movieId }})
}
```

please note i added a movieId paramter to `loadRouterLink` function. this is because the `movieid` is based on the v-for so the function should know what is the id (based on paramter - of course you can do it in other ways)

in your html you should send the correct id as paramter to this function

or you can do it in another way (same idea)

```
<v-carousel-item @click="movieId=movie.id"
        style="cursor:pointer"
        v-for="movie in popularMovies"
        :key="movie.title"
        :src="apiUrl + movie.poster_path"
      >
        <div class="carousel-title">
          <p>{{movie.title}}</p>
        </div>
        <router-link 
        :to="{ name: 'MovieDetails', params: { id: movie.id }}">
        VIEW MORE</router-link>
      </v-carousel-item>
    </v-carousel>
    <div style="text-align:center;">
      <v-btn @click="loadRouterLink">VIEW DETAILS</v-btn>
    </div>
```

and in the js part

```
{
    data(){
        return{movieId:0}
    },
    methods:{
         ...mapActions(["fetchPopularMovies"]),
    loadRouterLink () {
    this.$router.push({ name: 'MovieDetails', params: { id: this.movieId }})
    }
    }
}
```

source - https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/navigation.html

Comment: I try this and now I get error in console "Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined",

Comment: sounds like problem with your movies array which is not related to the `loadRouterFunction`. are you sure every movie have title property. please note you set it as key in v-for. and even put it as `carousel-title` so its must be exsist on each item in the array

Comment: I think the problem is that I can not access movie object outside of my carousel, in order to pass id as parameter to component method

Comment: of course you can't. its avaible only in the scope of v-for

Comment: Yes, and that is why I am trying to simulate (trigger) click on router-link element from another method

Comment: in the code above i simulate `router-link` but you need to supply the information to the function. just put the v-btn inside the carousel or put the v-for in div which will contain all the elements

Comment: That would break my layout

Comment: you have carousel **items** and one button which say view detailes. some how the button should know which  element you want to go to. you can do it by add data propery like movieId and in each `carousel-item` click event set the property to the movieid. and btw in this way the `loadRouterFunction` can read it from there and you dont need to send it as paramter